# Alternate way to load CodeIgniter libraries so that they play well with auto-complete

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, is it okay to load libraries & models like the following:

```
$my_library = new my_library();
```

The reason I want to do this is because the editor I use (Komodo Edit) does not recognize the class for use with autocomplete when using `$this->load`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In certain cases it is acceptable to load classes like that however you should stick to using the CodeIgniter loader class unless it's absolutely necessary not to.  I would urge you to convert your libraries and models to be compatible with the CodeIgniter loader class.

I understand what you mean when you say the autocomplete is not working.  I use NetBeans and this is a problem I ran into as well.  I did a little digging and although it's much less documented for Komodo Edit, the solution to getting autocomplete working correctly is very similar to getting it working with NetBeans.

First, here is a [Komodo Edit bug report](http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=77841) documenting the problem that you are having.  It's been open since 2008 so it's likely it won't ever be baked directly into the application since there is a simple workaround.

Here is a [blog post detailing the workaround](http://jimdoescode.blogspot.com/2010/10/hooray-for-codeigniter-code-completion.html).  The idea is that you create a dummy PHP file in the root of your project containing a number of comments referencing the properties and methods of the core CodeIgniter classes.  Komodo Edit will then reference the file and add the properties and methods to it's code completion.

The blog post looks a little outdated, but you should be able to easily modify it to get it working with whatever version of CodeIgniter you are using.

And if you're curious, here is a [blog post detailing the same solution for Netbeans](http://www.masnun.me/2010/06/16/codeigniter-code-completion-with-the-netbeans-ide-for-php.html).

Comment: Hmm.  Are you sure you added your application's models and not just the base CodeIgniter model?  I would still recommend you not load models they way you specified and use the CodeIgniter approach.  In my opinion it's not a good idea to bend the rules of the framework because your IDE isn't working correctly.

Comment: I added my model like this:  * @property Files_model $files_model      to the autocomplete.php under the controller class... it didn't work  When I type $this->file_mo ... no auto complete ever...

Comment: Did you add it under `Controller` or `CI_Controller`?  Unless you are using an older version of CodeIgniter, `Controller` should be renamed to `CI_Controller`.

Comment: okay this helped... Got it working now... 50+ to you! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a new approach I'm trying out for models that uses namespaces (5.3+) and `spl_autoload_register()`.  It wouldn't be too hard to get it to work for libraries too:

```
<?php

class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    protected static $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        self::$CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public static function autoload($class_name)
    {
        if (substr($class_name, 0, 7) == 'Models\\')
        {
            self::$CI->load->model(substr($class_name, 7));
        }
    }

    public function singleton($model_name)
    {
        if ( !class_exists('Models\\'.$model_name) || empty(self::$CI->$model_name))
        {
            $this->model($model_name);
        }

        return self::$CI->$model_name;
    }

    public function factory($model_name, $params = NULL)
    {
        if ( !class_exists('Models\\'.$model_name))
        {
            $this->model($model_name);
        }

        if (count($params) < 2)
        {
            return new self::$CI->$model_name($params);
        }
        else
        {
            $reflection_class = new ReflectionClass('Models\\'.$model_name);
            return $reflection_class->newInstanceArgs($params);
        }
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('MY_Loader::autoload');
```

**Reasons for namespaces:**

1. I constantly find myself wanting both an "Account" controller and an "Account" model, and it's nice not to worry about clashes
2. I automatically know in my autoloader that it's a model that should be loaded, so I can safely just load the model and be done

**Uses:**

- You can simply instantiate an object using `new ClassName()` as usual (your IDE should pick it up)
- You can load a singleton with `$this->load->singleton($class_name)`--*I still need some work on this part, as it wouldn't actually be a singleton if you autoloaded the first instance, and then used `$this->load->singleton()` after that.  This function is basically the same as `$this->load->model()` but is a little more self-descriptive.*
- You can load a factory instance with `$this->load->factory($class_name, $constructor_parameters)`.  It's nice because you can chain method calls and do some fancy database loading in the constructor based on the given parameters.

Comment: Okay maybe I will go this route with the extended loader class, but would it be safe to say that I could load models, libraries etc using new ClassName()  and not use the $this->load->model() way... or can I use both at the same time? I am a bit new to CI so I am not sure if its required to use load-> and/or if its bad practice to do both ways at the same time... My main purpose for needing this is only because autocomplete does not work when using $this->load, however I have no problem when using new ClassName() .. autocomplete works when doing that.

Comment: Yes, you could do either.  The autoloader basically calls `$this->load->model()` if the class isn't yet loaded.  This allows you to use `new ClassName()` as usual

Answer (score 0):

I don't think calling libraries like that would work. You could try and use the php include/require function to manually include the class in your page which in theory would allow you to create an instance in this way.

Forgive me but I don't understand what you mean by your editor is not recognizing it.

Comment: For some reason Komodo edit does not recognize the way CI loads libraries and models...  Thus autocomplete dropdown does not work unless you create a new instance of a class like this: $my_library = new my_library();

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add the library directory to your project properties ?
i think this can help http://community.activestate.com/node/7590 ( am not so sure since i dont use komodo)